# C# Visual Studio erro de compilação desconhecido

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Fui refatorar meu código em C# que estava funcionando perfeitamente, porém estava gigantesco, e ele parou de funcionar e o visual studio não descreve o erro em canto algum. Segue abaixo meu código e o Visual Studio.

**PrintScreen do console do Visual Studio**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**TicketController** - Minha controladora

```
using sgtalk.api.Helpers;
using sgtalk.api.Models;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace sgtalk.api.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TicketController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            //TicketRepository.GetAll(lg)
            HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            };

            if (LoginHelper.isLogged(Request, out LoginTransmit lg))
            {
                //    resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
                //    {
                //        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                //        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { }))
                //    };
            }
            else
            {
                resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
                };
            }

            return resp;
        }
    }
}
```

Analisando um pouco o código, descobri que o erro está na linha

```
LoginHelper.isLogged(Request, out LoginTransmit lg)
```

Removendo está linha o programa compila.

**LoginHelper** -- O prorietário da linha acima

```
using sgtalk.api.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace sgtalk.api.Helpers
{
    public static class LoginHelper
    {
        public static bool isLogged(HttpRequestMessage r, out LoginTransmit l)
        {
            l = null;
            var ret = false;
            if (r.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Access-Token", out IEnumerable<string> headerValues))
            {
                var s = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
                l = TokenHelper.Decode(s);
                ret = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

O que está acontecendo? Estou a mais de 1 hora tentando resolver, mas não encontro onde exatamente esta o erro.

Update: com "parou de funcionar" quero dizer que não compila mais.

Update 2: No console ele lista os seguintes erros:

> C:\Users\marcio.nicolau\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\sgtalk\sgtalk.api\Controllers\TicketController.cs(51,61,51,63): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Nestas linhas, tem estes códigos:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            //TicketRepository.GetAll(lg)
            HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            };
//linha 51
            if (LoginHelper.isLogged(Request, out LoginTransmit lg))
            {
                //    resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
                //    {
                //        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                //        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { }))
                //    };
            }
            else
            {
                resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
                };
            }

            return resp;
        }
```

> C:\Users\marcio.nicolau\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\sgtalk\sgtalk.api\Helpers\LoginHelper.cs(14,74,14,80): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'string'

```
public static bool isLogged(HttpRequestMessage r, out LoginTransmit l)
        {
            l = null;
            var ret = false;
            if (r.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Access-Token", out IEnumerable<string> headerValues)) //Linha 14
            {
                var s = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
                l = TokenHelper.Decode(s);
                ret = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Update 3: Estou usando .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: Se não me engano, no console (log), descreve o erro quando é assim. Coloca pra compilar e fica prestando atenção lá, talvez você ache alguma coisa.

Comment: Elabore: "_parou de funcionar_".

Comment: @LINQ Dei um update no post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qual versão de c# que está usando? Se for versões anterioes ou igual a 6.0, teste fazer isto:

```
LoginTransmit lg;
LoginHelper.isLogged(Request, out lg);
```